# Problem with updating data with different data sets in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am quite new in D3. I am trying to draw a lollipop chart based on a group of countries. On the html page, I have put some buttons allows users to change the selection of countries based on the continents the countries belong to.

The chart was successfully rendered when the page was loaded but things go wrong as soon as I click the buttons.

For example, when I clicked on 'Asia' button, the chart can show the line but the circles were missing.

And when I click 'Overview' button and try to see the overview of the countries, the chart only showed the line of the Asian countries that I just saw. The lines for other countries were missing, so did their circles.

I am following [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/alansmithy/e984477a741bc56db5a5) to try to update my chart with the .enter and .exit function, but I failed to update my chart as the example shown.

Dataset:

```
par_code,continent,country,date_1,camp_1,date_2,camp_2,date_3,camp_3
P027,Asia,China,09/05/2018,BBB,14/12/2018,AAA,,
P030,Asia,India,09/05/2018,BBB,18/09/2018,AAA,26/10/2018,CCC
P038,North America,United States,09/05/2018,BBB,14/12/2018,AAA,,
P042,Asia,Indonesia,09/05/2018,BBB,14/12/2018,AAA,,
P056,South America,Brazil,09/05/2018,BBB,14/12/2018,AAA,,
P058,Asia,Pakistan,09/05/2018,BBB,24/06/2018,AAA,28/11/2018,CCC
P059,Africa,Nigeria,09/05/2018,BBB,27/06/2018,AAA,,
P092,Asia,Bangladesh,09/05/2018,BBB,14/12/2018,AAA,,
P115,Europe,Russia,09/05/2018,AAA,13/05/2018,CCC,,
P134,Asia,Japan,09/05/2018,BBB,01/07/2018,AAA,13/12/2018,CCC
P154,North America,Mexico,09/05/2018,BBB,14/12/2018,AAA,,
P166,Asia,Philippines,09/05/2018,BBB,26/10/2018,FFF,,
P167,Asia,Vietnam,09/05/2018,BBB,12/12/2018,AAA,,
P168,Africa,Ethiopia,09/05/2018,BBB,25/10/2018,DDD,,
P170,Europe,Germany,09/05/2018,BBB,10/05/2018,EEE,,
P176,Africa,Egypt,09/05/2018,BBB,19/09/2018,AAA,,
P177,Asia,Iran,09/05/2018,BBB,12/12/2018,AAA,,
P180,Asia,Turkey,09/05/2018,AAA,25/10/2018,DDD,,
P182,Africa,Democratic Republic of the Congo,09/05/2018,BBB,25/10/2018,DDD,,
P183,Asia,Thailand,09/05/2018,BBB,12/12/2018,AAA,,
P184,Europe,France,09/05/2018,BBB,12/12/2018,AAA,,
P193,Europe,United Kingdom,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P194,Europe,Italy,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P197,Asia,Myanmar,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P199,Africa,South Africa,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P200,Asia,South Korea,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P201,Europe,Spain,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P202,Europe,Ukraine,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P203,South America,Colombia,09/05/2018,AAA,12/05/2018,CCC,,
P204,Africa,Tanzania,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P206,Africa,Sudan,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P207,Africa,Kenya,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P209,South America,Argentina,09/05/2018,AAA,12/05/2018,CCC,,
P210,Europe,Poland,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P213,Africa,Algeria,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P215,North America,Canada,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P216,Asia,Iraq,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P217,Africa,Morocco,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P218,Africa,Uganda,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P220,South America,Peru,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P221,South America,Venezuela,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
P222,Asia,Malaysia,09/05/2018,BBB,12/06/2018,CCC,,
```

The buttons on my HTML page that I used to update the chart:

```
<button onclick="updateChart('Overview')">Overview</button>
<button onclick="updateChart('Asia')">Asia</button>
<button onclick="updateChart('Africa')">Africa</button>
<button onclick="updateChart('Europe')">Europe</button>
<button onclick="updateChart('North America')">North America</button>
<button onclick="updateChart('South America')">South America</button>
```

The full js code:

```
const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 85 };
const width = 900;
const height = 700;

const svg = d3.select('#lollipop')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + Math.min(width, height) + ' ' + Math.min(width, 
height))
.attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin')

const g = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d/%m/%Y");

const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
.range([0, (width - margin.right - margin.left)]);

const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
.range([0, (height - margin.bottom - margin.top)])
.padding(1);

function x_gridlines() {
return d3.axisTop(xScale)
.ticks(5)
}

const beginDate = parseTime("01/05/2018");
let transTime = 100;
let duration;
let latestDate;
let dates = [];
let parsedDates;

d3.csv('../data/lollipop.csv')
.then(data => {

data.forEach(d => {
    d.continent = d.continent;
    d.country = d.country;

    d.camp_1 = d.camp_1;

    d.camp_2 = d.camp_2;

    d.camp_3 = d.camp_3;

    // determine latest date for x-axis
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        const date = `date_${i}`;

        if (d[date] !== '') {
            if (dates.indexOf(d[date]) === -1) {
                dates.push(d[date]);
            }
        }
    }

    d.date_1 = parseTime(d.date_1);
    d.date_2 = parseTime(d.date_2);
    d.date_3 = parseTime(d.date_3);

    if (d.date_3) {
        duration = d.date_3 - d.date_1;
    } else {
        duration = d.date_2 - d.date_1;
    }

    d.duration = duration;
});

parsedDates = dates.map(date => parseTime(date));

latestDate = d3.max(parsedDates);

// sort MP list according to duration
data.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.duration - b.duration;
})

let jumpList = data.map(d => d.country);

console.log(jumpList);

xScale.domain([beginDate, latestDate]);
yScale.domain(jumpList);

// grid
g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'grid')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
    .call(x_gridlines()
        .tickSize(-height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
        .tickFormat('')
    )

// define axes
g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis, x-axis')
    .call(d3.axisTop(xScale)
        .ticks(5)
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %Y')));

g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis, y-axis')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

// add lines
const timeline = g.selectAll('.timeline')
    .data(data, d => d.par_code);

timeline.enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr('class', 'timeline')
    .attr('x1', d => xScale(d.date_1))
    .attr('y1', d => yScale(d.country))
    .attr('x2', d => {
        if (d.date_3) {
            return xScale(d.date_3);
        } else if (d.date_2) {
            return xScale(d.date_2);
        }
    })
    .attr('y2', d => yScale(d.country))
    .attr('stroke', 'grey');

// add circles
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    const date = `date_${i}`;
    const camp = `camp_${i}`;

    g.selectAll('.circle')
        .data(data, d => d.par_code)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'time-circle')
        .attr('cx', d => xScale(d[date]))
        .attr('cy', d => yScale(d.country))
        .attr('r', '3')
        .style('fill', d => campColor(d[camp]));
}
})

function updateChart(area) {

d3.csv('../data/lollipop.csv')
.then(data => {

    if (area === 'Asia') {
        data = data.filter(d => d.continent === 'Asia');
    } else if (area === 'Europe') {
        data = data.filter(d => d.continent === 'Europe');
    } else if (area === 'South America') {
        data = data.filter(d => d.continent === 'South America');
    } else if (area === 'Africa') {
        data = data.filter(d => d.continent === 'Africa');
    } else if (area === 'North America') {
        data = data.filter(d => d.continent === 'North America');
    } else {
        data = data;
    }

    data.forEach(d => {
        d.continent = d.continent;
        d.country = d.country;

        d.camp_1 = d.camp_1;

        d.camp_2 = d.camp_2;

        d.camp_3 = d.camp_3;

        // determine latest date for x-axis
        for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            const date = `date_${i}`;

            if (d[date] !== '') {
                if (dates.indexOf(d[date]) === -1) {
                    dates.push(d[date]);
                }
            }
        }

        d.date_1 = parseTime(d.date_1);
        d.date_2 = parseTime(d.date_2);
        d.date_3 = parseTime(d.date_3);

        if (d.date_3) {
            duration = d.date_3 - d.date_1;
        } else {
            duration = d.date_2 - d.date_1;
        }

        d.duration = duration;
    });

    // sort MP list according to duration
    data.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.duration - b.duration;
    })

    // latestDate = d3.max(parsedDates);
    // console.log(latestDate);

    let jumpList = data.map(d => d.country);

    yScale.domain(jumpList);

    g.select('.y-axis')
        .transition()
        .duration(transTime)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

    // change lines position
    let timeline = g.selectAll('.timeline').data(data);

    timeline.exit().remove();

    timeline.enter()
        .append('line');

    timeline.transition()
        .attr('x1', (d) => xScale(d.date_1))
        .attr('y1', (d) => yScale(d.country))
        .attr('x2', (d) => {
            if (d.date_3) {
                return xScale(d.date_3);
            } else if (d.date_2) {
                return xScale(d.date_2);
            }
        })
        .attr('y2', (d) => yScale(d.country))
        .attr('stroke', 'grey');

    let newCircles = g.selectAll('.time-circle').data(data);

    newCircles.exit().remove();

    newCircles.enter()
    .append('circle')

    // change circles position
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        const date = `date_${i}`;
        const camp = `camp_${i}`;

        newCircles.transition()
            .duration(transTime)
            .attr('cx', d => {
                return xScale(d[date])
            })
            .attr('cy', d => yScale(d.country))
            .attr('r', '3')
            .style('fill', d => {
                return campColor(d[camp])
            });
    }
})
}

const campColor = (camp) => {
if (camp === 'AAA') {
return 'rgba(237,28,36,1)'
} else if (camp === 'BBB') {
return 'rgba(0,0,128,1)'
} else if (camp === 'CCC') {
return 'rgba(0,144,0,1)'
} else if (camp === 'DDD') {
return 'rgba(254,223,0,1)'
} else if (camp === 'EEE') {
return 'rgba(26,26,26,1)'
} else if (camp === 'FFF') {
return 'rgba(237,28,36,0.67)'
} else if (camp === 'GGG') {
return 'rgba(237,28,36,0.33)'
} else {
return 'rgba(255,165,0,1)';
}
}
```

I know it looks dumb for having too similar functions to load and update the same chart, but that's what I know so far.

So besides showing me how to update the chart correctly with the circles, I also need help on how to restructure the code better.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: how likely is it that your data changes for each `update()` call? Zero. So load the data once and use it during the whole session. Enable the buttons  when the data is loaded. Why don't you use the `area` variable in the filter arrow function?

Comment: have you checked the number of circles on your chart. There are not enough if you look at what the code wants to show.

Comment: if you post some code, post it all so we can easily test.

Comment: take back the comment on circle count, first reaction was while looking at the code and missing the error.